# How do ISPs divide their network for customers?

Tags: isp

I wanted to start ISP business in small town in India and there aren't any known sources whom I can directly contact and they will give me details about plans etc. Before I can convince my friends to join me and search for such contacts, I need to do some calculations.

One of my friend told me that we can get 10Mbps connection and divide it in customers using Amplifier(never heard of it) and by using it we can provide 50 customers or even more with 1Mbps speed at the same time and they will all get that much speed. Any such thing is possible?

Any information on how does it work will be great.

Comment: There's things like local caching and compression (not as useful these days as it used to be in the past) and multicast (which is quite complex to get working properly). But otherwise there's no such thing. Contention is the key strategy here. You can give 50 people 1Mbps, but not all at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no amplifier for bandwidth speed.
If you want 50 customers with 1Mbps at the same time, you need 50Mbps bandwidth.

The thing that ISPs relay on is that most users will most of the time not use most of their bandwidth, so they fit-in more clients (10 or even way more for fiber optic lines), which is true, considering at a speed of 100Mbps you can transfer 1TB in under 24h.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that not all of your customers will be using all their bandwidth at the same time. So you can "overcommit" quite a bit.

But if you know so little about the ISP business that you don't understand the basic concepts that ground it, why do you want to start an ISP?

Comment: Because all ISPs here charge a lot, just few miles away somebody provides service at almost half rates which I feel is unfair. Plus it is good opportunity as there is a lot of development going on here.

Comment: @ZorroHere Likely it's because the "last mile" is more expensive where you are.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz is right. By the time you buy the service an re-sell you'll just lose money, especially if you have no idea what you're doing. At 20Mb 5:1 contention isnt terrible but at 1Mb one customer watching youtube means 4 having nothing.

Comment: A lot of community ISPs aren't in it to make money. Most community projects would never get off the ground if everyone had the same attitude as you guys. You'll also find a lot of staff in companies haven't the faintest clue how the low level technology works. There's a reason managers aren't techs, and techs aren't managers.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq His desire to start an ISP flowed from the observed market prices, but he doesn't understand the basic economics of ISPs. Discouraging people from doing things that are poorly thought out or that they are not competent to do is just as important encouraging people to do things that are well thought out and that they are competent to do.

Comment: And I repeat.  Most community projects would never get off the ground if everyone had the same attitude as you guys. I don't see anywhere where it is indicated encouraging or discouraging other people's ideas is anything to do with the remit of Superuser. This is a Q&A site, not the idea police or a site for critiquing business pitches.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq Only the most terrible expert merely answers specific questions. Competent experts tells people what they need to know, whether they realize it or not. If a project is poorly thought out, it shouldn't get off the ground. We don't have the resources to do everything we can imagine, and it only makes sense to devote effort to the things that we are best able to do.

Comment: And I repeat, I don't see anywhere where it is indicated encouraging or discouraging other people's ideas is anything to do with the remit of Superuser. This is a Q&A site, not the idea police or a site for critiquing business pitches.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq It's not a site for giving irresponsible, but technically correct, answers either.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz We aren't going to jump into it blindly. Right now we are trying to get information on what will our monthly expenses be and if we can get enough revenue. As far as my question is concerned, I too found it practically impossible but I had access to control panel of my current ISP who provides maximum speed of 4mbps and maximum data exchange of his router never crossed 4-5mbps even when he has around 150 customers. And about knowledge, my current ISP couldn't configure network adapter on his own on windows(Linux or OSX could have been understandable).

Comment: @ZorroHere Be careful. The speeds you're looking at might be five minute averages. You can have a line whose five minute average never exceeds 5Mbps, but if you replaced it with a 5Mbps line you'd see a huge reduction in service. Also, make sure you look closely at peak times. Then again, if all the other alternatives are much worse, you may do well even if you don't always give people their full bandwidth. Good luck.

Comment: A good start tactic for a small ISP is to have non-power-user clients, clients that do not use traffic in a very heavy manner (torrenters, streamers, etc). Later on, you can increase the BW and get any type of client.